# PHP To ECHO Cell Values On Tabs

Tags: php

I have been looking around at a few PHP classes that spit out exactly what the excel document shows (just one tab).

However, what I am trying to do is read some data from an xls file that has multiple tabs to get the latest petrol prices in the UK (https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/345195/weekly_fuel_prices.xls)

from each year, e.g. 2014 - the date and the ULSP in an array - is this even possible to go through each tab (year and do this), can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which libraries have you looked at: I can think of at least two that can do this, including my own PHPExcel library

Comment: excel_reader2.php I believe it was called

Comment: [PHP_Excel_Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) and [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) are the two libraries I know that will generate the HTML for you without your needing to write all the markup yourself